# How to convert a list<list<object>> to object[,]?

Tags: c#

I have the following static class to build an dynamic object Array:

```
public class oDataArray
{
    public static List<List<object>> GetDataObject(DbCommand command)
    {
        List<List<object>> oDataList = new List<List<object>>();

        using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    List<object> oData = new List<object>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        oData.Add(dr[i]);
                    }
                    oDataList.Add(oData);
                }
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
        return oDataList;
    }
}
```

I tried to convert it to a 2 dimensional object array via:

```
object[,] myNewObjectArray = oDataArray.GetDataObject(anyDbCommand).ToArray<object>().ToArray<object>();
```

But it will not work!? :( 
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why create a list of lists, if you need an array?

Comment: AFAIK there is no direct way to generate a 2D array. If you really want it, you should copy the elements. What is possible with linq is to generate a jagged array `object[][]`

Comment: Why do you want a 2D array in the first place? And why use a list of lists? Eg you can use `GetValues()` to read all fields at once

Comment: The problem with `object[,]` is that you need to know the row count.

Comment: That line should give you the error "Cannot implicitly convert type ... ". Which should tell you that you are using the wrong types. Doing `ToArray` twice is pointless, because after converting the list of lists to an array of lists with the first `ToArray` the second `ToArray` will change your array of lists to (guess what?) an array of lists which it already is! It's a good thing to always include the errors you get in your question on this site. Also, "But it will not work!? :( What I'm doing wrong?" is very vague. You should read [ask].

Comment: A `object[,]` and `List<List<object>>` are not really compatible. The assumption is that all sub lists have same count of items. A Jagged array is IMHO the best solution (if you don't want to have lists as result) `object[][]`

Comment: @MPA what is the *actual* problem that you want to solve with a 2D array? It's probably easier to solve to actual problem than generate a 2D array in an efficient way. Converting an arbitrary number of rows to such an array means copying data, thus wasting CPU and memory. Why not use a DataTable or list of object arrays?

Comment: A better way would be storing it in a `DataTable` if you want all rows in mem

Comment: Your `oDataList` represents collection of "rows" where row is collection of column values. What data you expect to be in [,] array?

Comment: `List<List<object>>` is *jagged*, not rectangular; the closest you'll get is `object[][]`, not `object[,]`

Answer (score 1):

How about,

oDataArray.GetDataObject(anyDbCommand).Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray();

Some explanation:

- Select(a => a.ToArray()) crates an enumerable of type object[],
- ToArray() creates an array of arrays.

Comment: A jagged array `object[][]` is not the same as a 2-dimensional array `object[,]`. So you don't really answer the question.

Comment: @PJvG IMO that's because the question is wrong; `List<List<object>>` is also jagged, so this is the expected and natural result